# Cannot get python module ezsheets to work

Tags: python

I followed the steps from the official documentation for ezsheets. Both apis were activated (sheets and drive) and I turned on a python shell and imported the ezsheets module. But, it did not open the new browser window like the documentation said it's supposed to. I then tried and successfully got google sheets working with googles' quickstart script. I have the credentials-sheets.json and token.pickle in the same folder as my python scripts. Sheets api seems to work just fine on it's own but when I try it with ezsheets module I get a following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/method/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_projects-sgt8dc05/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ezsheets/__init__.py", line 1559, in listSpreadsheets
    if not IS_INITIALIZED: init()
  File "/home/method/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_projects-sgt8dc05/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ezsheets/__init__.py", line 1520, in init
    creds = flow.run_local_server()
  File "/home/method/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_projects-sgt8dc05/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 443, in run_local_server
    host, port, wsgi_app, handler_class=_WSGIRequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 153, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 470, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Answer (score 0):

ezsheets is trying to open webserver on port 8000 to obtain access token. But it is already occupied by another app.
Chech what app listens on port 8000 and close it.

On Linux you can check it with

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8000
```

On Windows:

```
netstat -ab
```

Comment: Netstat command returns no response. Perhaps I could somehow change the default port on the module? I checked without grep, there's nothing on port 8000.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help